# How to fix the ping between the server and every client?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic

I have a server for a very competitive game which involves money. In order for the game to be fair, every client must have the same ping. I can't, obviously, make everyone have a short ping. So the only solution is to fix it high: for example, 200ms is acceptable.

The problem is, how do I **force** a ping to be 200ms? In order for that to work, I'd have to know how much I should delay sending the packets - and, for that, I'd have to know the ping of the client. So, if the ping is 60ms, I could just add a 140ms delay to provided data. The problem is: I can only know the ping by asking it, and a client can **lie**, telling me his ping is higher than it is and making me send the packets earlier.

How to solve that problem?

Comment: what is the isp u are using?

Answer (score 0):

you can't fix the ping, it can change all the time. if your client enable e.g. torrent during your ping discovery it will significantly affects the result.

but maybe you don't have to delay sending packets. maybe it's enough to delay receiving or analyzing them? and that might be easier, you just have to know when you sent the corresponding packet

there is also other option: many online shooters use feature called 'unlagged'. client sends the coordinate of his shoot and server, based on current ping (lets say 80ms) calculate if the target would have been hit 80ms ago. if so, the target is considered hit. but this of course introduces some artifacts like the victim getting the shot through the wall.

Answer (score 0):

By 'ping' I assume you mean 'network latency', which is variable and entirely outside your control. Your question doesn't make sense.